# In Solr 4.0, are soft committed docs to master node visible to slave nodes immediately?

Tags: solr, replication

My search backend tries to upgrade to Solr 4.0 from Solr 3.6.

The existing arch based on Solr 3.6 has 1 master Solr node with 2 slave Solr nodes for load balancing, whose master node is for updating docs only and slave nodes are read-only. Everything N minutes, docs are committed to master node then slave nodes poll indexed docs and install them, so these docs are visible.

In Solr 4.0, because soft committed docs are not sync-ed to disk files, my question is that if I upgrade to Solr 4.0 and **don't use SolrCloud**, are soft committed docs to master Solr node visible to slaves nodes immediately.

If these are visible to slave, how it works, via zookeeper?

Answer (score 5):

The solr pull replication mechanism just copies the segment files on disk, nothing more. Soft-committed documents are not on disk (not fsynced yet, which is done when a commit happens), that's why they won't be pulled while replicating.

Like elasticsearch always did, SolrCloud uses the push approach. When you index documents they will be indexed on all the nodes they are supposed to be indexed. That's why soft-committed documents can be seen on all nodes they are indexed.

Comment: <The solr pull replication mechanism just copies the segment files on disk, nothing more. Soft-committed documents are not on disk (not fsynced yet, which is done when a commit happens), that's why they won't be pulled while replicating.>if this is the expected behavior, i am committing every hourly but i could see the documents updated meanwhile. Is there any caveat for using softcommit ?